# Force Touch Events for UWP Application

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, touch

I've got a JavaScript based UWP application and inside of that I'm using fullcalendar. It's not functioning correctly via the touchscreen, and that appears to be because the webview is generating mouse events instead of touch events, i.e. instead of `touchstart` it receives `mousedown`.

Is there a way to force the web view to generate touch events only? This will only ever be run on hybrid devices.

Comment: I made a basic demo, but didn't reproduce the problem. Could you please try it on a blank empty app?

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks for taking a look!